# What are the requirements for Gentiles to listen to a Jewish prophet?

Tags: navi-prophets, sheker-false, yonah-jonah-book-of, false-prophet

Follow-up to my [previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85039/5275) relating to false prophets:

Devarim 18:18-22 says that one is required to listen to a true prophet but not a false prophet.

Do these laws apply to Gentiles? I am curious b/c Jonah revealed a prophetic message to the people of Ninveh. It seems that they listened to him and did Teshuva and they were spared. But being Gentiles, were they required to listen to Jonah in the first place?

Furthermore, within the discussion in Devarim, it says that when a prophet speaks in the G-d's name and the action never occurs, he is a false prophet and he should die. Jonah's prediction never occurred. Could the people of Nineveh claim that he was a false prophet and have killed him or these rules don't apply to Gentiles?

Comment: It is probably a toladah of one of the seven commandments of Noah. But to confirm that would require reflection. Bnai Noach are required to accept that their commandments come to them today via Moshe Rabbeinu at Har Sinai.

Comment: 1. **Jonah's negative prophecy was on condition**, as usual, negative prophecies occur unless the people are forgiven, so the fact it didn't happen does not invalidate the prophecy.

Comment: 2. what do you mean by "apply"? Do you mean "is a gentile killed if he didn't hear to our prophet"? Gentiles have השגחה כללית not השגחה פרטית, so what do you expect from gentiles listening to our prophet.

Comment: 3. Gentiles had their own prophets like Bil'am so they definitely **can hear** to their prophets.